# Grafana 7: How to hide table column but still use its value in a data link

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

Please note this is for Grafana 7

Just upgraded to version 7 and now I can not work out how to hide a column in a Table Panel but still use its value in a Data Link.

I select 3 columns, the first being ID that I do not want to display but instead use its value in a link on one of the displayed columns.  For the data link I use the following '/d/ddsds/dashboard-name?var-id=${__data.fields[id]}' which works when the ID field is displayed.  If I use a Transform rule to hide the column then the link no longer works as the ID value does not get placed in the URL.

Also tried using '${__data.fields[id]:raw}'

Comment: did you get the solution for this? I am also looking for the same.

Comment: I placed the column last and set the column width to 1 (0 doesn't work). This is of course a hacky solution, and it doesn't look perfect, but good enough

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the fix or functionality [may be delayed until version 8.0.0](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/24092):

`@torkelo torkelo modified the milestones: 7.4.0, 8.0.0 on Jan 18`.

Until then I use the following workaround; Basically what I do is set the width to 1.:

[image]

Even using this workaround, the column will still look a minimum of pixels. You can reduce the visibility of this by moving the column you want to hide to the last position:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is already solved but will be released in 7.2.

Issue: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/24092

Comment: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/25289#issuecomment-652566179

Comment: it's not fixed: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/24092#issuecomment-717602484, but you could make data column less visible by placing it as last and with `witdth=1`

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You can do this by add Organize felds in Transform, which only support one single frame so if you have two query, you should join them first.

Comment: I had already tried that, like I mentioned in my question if I hide that field then the variable replacement in the URL does not work

Comment: It hides the column but again the value replacement in the link stops working.  Maybe there is another string that I use in the link instead of ${__data.fields[id]}, after all the field is nolonger displayed

Answer (score -1):

try to use `${__data.fields[id]}` insted of `${__data.fields[id]:raw}`

Comment: once you remove it in transform there is no field in the data object, so using raw or not doesnt matter